# Parity transaction tracing and how to determine transaction/call failure or success

Tags: transactions, parity, payments, transaction-trace

I am currently working on a in-payment monitor system for Ethereum using the trace functionality in the Parity Ethereum Client.

The reason I am using the trace functionality instead of just looking up transactions is because I want to be able to pick up payments from contracts of any form, shape and size. My understanding is that a contract can generate any number of sub-calls which may or may not transfer ether to an account (or another contract). If this is not the right way to go about making a "universal in payment monitor" please yell at me.

My understanding is also that any number of things can happen to not only the entire transaction but also any sub-calls within the transaction which may or may not fault the entire transaction or parts of the transaction and sub-calls within it.

So my question is how does one accurately and securely determine if a given transaction and (sub)call has failed or succeeded? There seems to be a lack of good functionality for people who develop low-level wallet and exchange style monitors. This is pretty important to get right as well, much moneys could be lost.

This is what I am doing currently:

1. Fetch transaction and transaction block over RPC API for basic validation (eth_getTransactionByHash and eth_getBlockByHash).
2. Fetch transaction receipt over RPC API to check status field (0x1 = success, anything else = fail) (eth_getTransactionReceipt).
3. Fetch transaction trace over RPC API for detailed validation (check if error field is present in payment-spesific (sub)call) (trace_transaction).

More specifically I am wondering if its necessary to do any more validation of the (sub)call trace path (parent calls). If a parent call fails, does that mean all sub-calls fail as well? Or does this not matter? I have seen evidence and information for both cases.

One example is this transaction: https://blockchair.com/ethereum/transaction/0x626590b434e06b79fdd2187b28a55569f6c0636c6806808beb6ce2c743e88188

It shows that the sub-call (0.0.2.0.0.0.1) failed, but it has further sub-calls 0.0.2.0.0.0.1.0, 0.0.2.0.0.0.1.1 and 0.0.2.0.0.0.1.2 which seems to have succeeded. But then again no ether was transferred in those sub-calls so idk. Obviously, unless there is a bug in blockchair.com, a sub-call of a failed parent call can be successful, but does anyone actually know the rules at play here?

EDIT:
After some scanning through the Ethereum blockchain I also found this transaction: https://blockchair.com/ethereum/transaction/0x52c77e78c8d74e8fca4fc5760b8ed3775befeb9c072904b8c3568f2a5916aca9

It also shows sub-calls being successful after a failed parent call, this time also with ether being transferred (non zero value). However this time I am having a hard time seeing if this actually succeeded. Especially when one of the sub-calls are using a ether value that failed to transfer in a parent call. Checking the transaction on etherscan does indeed show that the state diff are not reflecting the seemingly successful sub-call of 0.000002 ETH (https://etherscan.io/tx/0x52c77e78c8d74e8fca4fc5760b8ed3775befeb9c072904b8c3568f2a5916aca9#statechange)

This leads me to believe that any sub-calls performed by a parent call that failed also have failed. Especially noticing that value that is transferred by a parent-call sometimes is used by subsequent calls.

EDIT2:
After scanning through several hundred thousand blocks and millions of transactions I am concluding this on my own. The rule seems to be consistent; If a parent call has failed, so has all subsequent sub-calls. Which totally makes sense. Feel free to comment if you have something you want to add or elaborate on.

This is one of many transactions that makes it clear: https://blockchair.com/ethereum/transaction/0x2fdf456085e159a0b52776b01472b8d5d0d37a31be15578466c7e3e82c456fb5

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x2fdf456085e159a0b52776b01472b8d5d0d37a31be15578466c7e3e82c456fb5/advanced#internal

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x2fdf456085e159a0b52776b01472b8d5d0d37a31be15578466c7e3e82c456fb5/advanced#statechange